# Python PriorityQueue join up to specific priority

Tags: python, concurrency, priority-queue

I'm trying to implement a [PriorityQueue](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/queue.html#queue.PriorityQueue) with a [join](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/queue.html#queue.Queue.join) function that blocks until all items in the queue *up to a specified priority* have been gotten and processed. Unfortunately, I'm stuck because I think I need to specify that priority cutoff value ahead of time when I'm adding items to the queue.

I'm trying to implement a function with the following signature:

```
def join_until_priority(self, priority):
```

But from the implementation of the Python `queue.Queue`, it looks like the `join()` function is based on waiting for a counter of `unfinished_tasks` to reach `0`.

I think this means I would have to know the desired priority cutoff value at "insertion time" instead of at "join time" so that I can create the counter of `unfinished_priority_1000_tasks` for example.

This seems like a reasonably common task to me so I was surprised it's not supported by default. Or is there a simpler approach that I'm missing?